# how to convert FormData to request body string?

Tags: javascript

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('name1', 'value1');
fd.append('name2', 'value2');
fd.append('name3', new Blob([`zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz`]));
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(`POST`, location.href);
xhr.send(fd);
```

in devtools network panel, request body string is

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryTUux0YL1tLSIGtnn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name1"

value1
------WebKitFormBoundaryTUux0YL1tLSIGtnn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name2"

value2
------WebKitFormBoundaryTUux0YL1tLSIGtnn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name3"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
------WebKitFormBoundaryTUux0YL1tLSIGtnn--
```

[image]

so How to convert FormData to request body string ?

```
const formDataToString = (fd: FormData): string => {
  // TODO
  return ``;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I find we can use Request, but it is asynchronous

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('name1', 'value1');
fd.append('name2', 'value2');
fd.append('name3', new Blob([`zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz`]));
const req = new Request(location.origin, {
  method: `POST`,
  body: fd,
});
const td = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
console.log(td.decode(await req.arrayBuffer()));
```

Is there a way to do this without `async/await` ?